# Where was this destroyed bridge in South Vietnam?

Tags: military, identification, vietnam-war, bridge

Can anyone provide the location of this destroyed bridge during the Vietnam War? I believe the sign at the end of the bridge refers to the Big Red One, 1st Infantry Division[image]

Comment: The bridge style is distinctive, but very common. It's a [Bailey-style bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey_bridge), very widely used after WWII by military engineering units. US forces would have erected plenty of them in Vietnam.

Comment: I blew the photo up to 1200 dpi. The patch in the upper left of the photo is very distinctive, green with the red numeral one. Other photos in the collection are fromthe same division.

Comment: What was the source of this photo? It is probably useful to include that information to help research answers.

Comment: A collection of photos from the same person in Vietnam were purchased on ebay.